# Populate DataTable with JSON data on Click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm fetching the details of a single entity and i want to display it in a table. I'm using DataTable for this, up to now i have fetched the single entity JSON like below:

```
$CxRecordsTable.delegate('form', 'submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    var quizId = $form.attr('id');

    $.post('<?php echo $this->CxHelper->Route('eb-admin-get-evaluation-quiz-by-id')?>', {
        id: quizId
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        quizDetail = jqXHR.responseText;
    });
```

Now i want `quizDetail` which is a single Entity JSON String to show it in dataTable. In simple words i want this entity to be displayed in DataTable, what i tried is below:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(quizDetail) //for testing
//Load  datatable
var table = $("#cx-evaluation-quiz-details-table");
table.DataTable ({
    data : jsonString,
    "columns" : [
        { "first_name" : "first_name" },
        { "gender" : "gender" },
        { "email" : "email" },
        { "phone" : "phone" },
        { "age" : "age" },
        { "version" : "version" },
        { "date" : "date" }
    ]}
);
```

MY HTML Table Code:

```
<table id="cx-evaluation-quiz-details-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th class="hasinput">
                <input type="text" class="form-control filter" placeholder="First Name">
            </th>
            <th class="hasinput">
                <input type="text" class="form-control filter" placeholder="Gender" />
            </th>
            <th class="hasinput">
                <input type="text" class="form-control filter" placeholder="Email" />
            </th>
            <th class="hasinput">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control filter" placeholder="Phone" />
            </th>
            <th class="hasinput">
                <input type="text" class="form-control filter" placeholder="Age" />
            </th>
            <th class="hasinput">
                <input type="text" class="form-control filter" placeholder="Version" />
            </th>

            <th class="hasinput">
                <input type="text" class="form-control filter" placeholder="Date" />
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th class="all">First Name</th>
            <th class="all">Gender</th>
            <th class="all">Email</th>
            <th class="all">Phone</th>
            <th class="all">Age</th>
            <th class="all">Version</th>
            <th class="all">Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Backend GetQuizBYId Code:

```
public function getEvaluationQuizByIdAction() {
    // Get the clicked evaluation quiz id
    $id = $this->request->get('id', null);

    // Return Evaluation Quiz record
    $cxEbEvaluation = CxEbEvaluation::getEvaluationByIdForDataTable($id);

    // Return data array
    return array('data' => $cxEbEvaluation);
}
```